# Open iTerm and run Vim from a directory in Finder (OS X)

Tags: macos, mac, vim, terminal, finder

Is it possible (maybe with Apple Script or something) when I'm in a folder in OSX's finder to open iTerm and run `vim` with this folder as the working directory?

This would be useful to quickly create a text document in a folder without navigating there manually on the Terminal with `cd`.

I'm using OS X  Yosemite, iTerm2 and the homebrew build of VIM.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if they work with the latest Mac OS X but you can try some of the many applescript solutions that have been floating the web for years. [This page](http://peterdowns.com/posts/open-iterm-finder-service.html) has many relevant informations, snippets and links.

I've had Terminal.app and iTerm.app versions of that idea sitting in my Finder toolbar for years.

You'll obviously need to change their code to make them start Vim too.

There's also [a MacVim version](http://blog.shinyfrog.net/2008/06/07/finder-droplets-mac-editors/) that's IMO closer to what you want.

That said, you can simply drag the current folder on iTerm's icon in the dock.

Answer (score 0):

you can always open a terminal, type "cd " and drag the folder. then type "vim .", but this is far away from an automated solution.

when you drag the folder, you don't have to type the path.

Comment: Although it's a really handy thing to drag a folder in there, it's not really what I'm looking for.